# Polygon Vertices as complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Here is the problem:

> i) A regular n-sided polygon has vertices $p_0,p_1 , ... p_{n-1}$ that lie on a circle of unit radius.
> By considering the complex roots of the equation $z^n = 1$ or otherwise, prove that the product of the
> distances $p_0p_1,p_0p_2 , ... p_0p_{n-1}=n$ [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfB6d.png)]

My logic so far is that the equation $z^n=1$ has $n$ many solutions by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, therefore we can write $1=z^n=(z-z_1)(z-z_2)\cdots(z-z_n)$. We can take the absolute value of both sides to get $|1|=|z-z_1|\times|z-z_2|\times\cdots\times|z-z_n|$. This close to what is desired with the only difference beeing that $z$ is a generic point on the circle not equal to one of the roots. Could somebody give me a hint as to how to proceed with this problem?

Comment: If $z^n=1$ then $|z|^n=1$ so $|z|=1,$ so $z$ is on the circle of unit radius centered at $0.$ Thus $z= \cos\alpha + i\sin\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in[0,2\pi).$ So
$$\begin{align}
z^n & = (\cos\alpha + i\sin\alpha)^n \\ {} \\
& = \cos(n\alpha) + i\sin(n\alpha) \\ {} \\
& = 1 \text{ if and only if } \cos(n\alpha)=1 \text{ and } \sin(n\alpha) = 0.
\end{align}$$

Comment: So we have
$$
\alpha \in \left\{0, \frac{2\pi} n ,\frac{4\pi} n, \frac{6\pi} n, \ldots, \frac{2(n-1)\pi} n \right\} = \left\{ \frac{2k\pi}  n : k=0,1,2,\ldots, n-1 \right\}.
$$
So $p_k = e^{2\pi ki/n}$ and in particular $p_0=1.$
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \operatorname{distance}(p_0,p_k) = \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \big| e^{2\pi ki/n} - 1\big|$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiate your equation 
$$nz^{n-1}=\frac{d}{dz}(z-z_1)...(z-z_n)$$

All the terms formed when we differentiate vanish when we put $z=z_1$ except for $$(z-z_2)...(z-z_n)$$ which becomes 
$$(z_1-z_2)...(z_1-z_n)$$

So $$n=n|z_1|^{n-1}=|z_1-z_2|...|z_1-z_n|$$

Is that OK now?

Comment: Hello, when I do that I get $nz^(n-1)=0$. From here I can use the expansion for $z^n$ from before to get similar to the desired equation but I get that the product is equal to zero. Could you clarify on what you meant as the next step? Thanks!

Comment: Much clearer, thank you for your explanation.